# SD writing capable SSH server for Android Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, ssh

Is there any SSH Server for android (similar to SSHelper or SSH Droid) that will allow me to write to the (external) SD card *without* having to root my tablet?

Whenever I search for this kind problem, I end up in pages that say basically "Kit-kat dont like SD, you need to root". However, since I updated to Marshmallow things look much better for the SD: many apps that could not write to it now can.

Is this actually a limitation on these apps (i.e. not some problem with my tablet)?
If so: is it due to a special technical difficulty (i.e. it is somehow more difficult to implement writing to the SD in an SSH server than for, say, a PDF annotator) or is it just not implemented?

My tablet is Samsung Galaxy Tab A with S-pen. Android is version 6.0.1